# Using the %in% statement with knit_expand

Tags: r, r-markdown

When using the `knitr::knit_expand()` function I would like to do something like

```
knit_expand(text="filter(df, col1 %in% {{x}})")
```

where `x` is a simple vector of strings or numbers. This example would not work though, I'm wondering if such a thing is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may need to `paste` to create the format

```
knitr::knit_expand(text="filter(df, col1 %in% {{sprintf('c(%s)', toString(x))}})")
```

-output

```
[1] "filter(df, col1 %in% c(7, 2, 3))"
```

which is similar to using `glue::glue`

```
glue::glue("filter(df, col1 %in% {sprintf('c(%s)', toString(x))})")
```

---

Or may also `deparse` (if there are strings as well).  The above method need `sQuote` or `dQuote` on the vector  before doing the `toString`) i.e.

```
knitr::knit_expand(text="filter(df, col1 %in% {{sprintf('c(%s)', toString(dQuote(x, FALSE)))}})")
```

Or use `deparse`

```
knitr::knit_expand(text="filter(df, col1 %in% {{deparse(x)}})")
```

-output

```
[1] "filter(df, col1 %in% c(7, 2, 3))"
```

If it is a string

```
x <- c(7, 2, 3, 'a')
cat(knitr::knit_expand(text="filter(df, col1 %in% {{deparse(x)}})"), "\n")
filter(df, col1 %in% c("7", "2", "3", "a"))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(7, 5, 3, 2, 9, 7))
x <- c(7, 2, 3)
```